# Flutter web app in a subfolder just returns to the root page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a Flutter portfolio app at suragch.dev and then a few other web apps in an `apps` subfolder. However, when I push the changes and try to visit the new Flutter app in the subfolder

```
https://suragch.dev/apps/mongoleditor/
```

it returns to the root Flutter page. In the past I didn't have this problem. In fact, another flutter app in the apps folder works fine:

```
https://suragch.dev/apps/mongolcode/
```

How do I fix this?

*I found the answer and will add it below.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now when you build a Flutter web app that isn't being served from the root, you need to change the base in the app's **index.html** file. This is described in that file's comments:

> If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change
> the href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.
>
> The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order
> for it to work correctly.
>
> For more details:
>
> - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

So just change this:

```
<base href="/">
```

to this:

```
<base href="https://suragch.dev/apps/mongoleditor/">
```